# Store hash initialisation to a variable

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

There is a code in my Sinatra app

```
    - if flash[:error]
      .alert.alert-error
        %button.close{:type =>" button", "data-dismiss"=>"alert"}x
        = flash[:error]
    - if flash[:warning]
      .alert.alert-warning
        %button.close{:type =>" button", "data-dismiss"=>"alert"}x
        = flash[:warning]
    - if flash[:info]
      .alert.alert-info
        %button.close{:type =>" button", "data-dismiss"=>"alert"}x
        = flash[:info]
```

Is there any way to simply it?  In particular, is there any way to get rid of repeating `:type =>" button", "data-dismiss"=>"alert"` hash initialisations by storing them as a variable?

Comment: when there is so little HTML structure and so much Ruby code, a helper is preferable

Comment: @AlanDert - can you please make sure your comments are [in English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118678/how-should-we-handle-wholly-non-english-comments). Thanks.

Comment: Who on Earth downvoted me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
- flash.each do |type, message|
  .alert{ :class => "alert-#{type}" }
    %button.close{:type =>" button", "data-dismiss"=>"alert"}x
    = message
```

Comment: `undefined method  each  for Rack::Flash::FlashHash`

Comment: ah its different from the rails flash. Try this out: https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash